# Show that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \int_0^k x^n (1-k^{-1}x)^k dx=n!$ using Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Show that $\lim_{k\to \infty} \int_0^k x^n (1-k^{-1}x)^k dx=n!$

[image]

I'm trying to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem and the fact that $\int_0^\infty x^n e^{-x}dx=n!$.

So I let $f_k(x)=x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^k \chi_{[0,k]}$. Then since $(1-k^{-1}x)^k \to e^{-x}$ as $k \to \infty$ we have $f_k(x) \to x^ne^{-x}\chi_{[0,\infty)}$.

So my desired $g$ and $f$ in the Theorem are $x^n e^{-x} \chi_{[0,\infty)}$, but to use the theorem, I need to show that $|f_k| \le g$ a.e. for all $k$.This is where I'm struggling, how do I show that $|(1-k^{-1} x)^k|\le e^{-x}$?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Use that  the sequence $(1-\frac{x}{k})^k\chi_{[0,k]}$ is monotone increasing to $e^{-x}$ and so is dominated by it.

Comment: @Svetoslav I think this is exactly what he wants to prove.

Comment: @JimmyR.  I think, he wants, to prove it is bounded by the limit. And I suggested to see that it is monotone increasing (which is a standard limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$. This yields the inequality
$$1+x\leqslant e^x.$$
It follows that
$$1-k^{-1}x\leqslant e^{-k^{-1} x}, $$
and exponentiating we have
$$(1-k^{-1}x)^k\leqslant e^{-x}. $$
We conclude that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^k x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^k \ \mathsf dx = \int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x}\ \mathsf dx = \Gamma(n+1)=n!.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $k\in \mathbb{N}$, by the binomial theorem you have
$$
\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^k \leq \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{x^n}{n!}.
$$

Comment: but is it true for $x<0$ ?